# Html or web without JS environment?

Tags: javascript, html, web

With respect to HTML/web .... [The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript) 
points out that in some cases there won't be any JavaScript support.

Do such environment - without JavaScript still exist or this is an old article ?

Comment: yes, and many people enable things like noscript

Comment: You can use [<noscript>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) tag in such cases to display a warning message.

Comment: The more interesting question is "Are the small number of browsers that might have javascript disabled worth making and testing a whole version of your site that has meaningful functionality without javascript"?  That seems like a lot of extra work for a small number of users who probably could enable javascript if they really cared to use your site.  I'd rather spend that time moving the site forward and making it even more useful and attractive to those who do have JS enabled.

Comment: @jfriend00 yep that is right, but I am keen on knowing cases where javascript would be disabled while viewing webpages.

Comment: @JohnSmith A lot of people disable it because they _just_ want the information or because they have a slow connection and don't want to wait 5 minutes for the page to display because it is waiting on ajax.googleapis.com (or whatever) and the rest of the addons, adware, trackware and bloat.  Try using netsurf sometime (though they now have experimental javascript capability), you'll be amazed.

Answer (score 0):

The article you posted is long. It does cover many practices that are good to use today. I wanted to address a few statements the article made on assumptions.

> Assumption: everybody’s browser supports JavaScript. Not true: In
>   order to be unobtrusive to users, taking away the script should not
>   preclude them from using your site, even though their interaction will
>   be far less rich than that of users whose browser does support
>   JavaScript.

All major browsers such as Chrome, Safari, IE, Firefox, and Opera support Javascript. Users may manually disable it, but you can assume most of your users will have Javascript. However, you can use a `<noscript>` tag as a precaution for users that do not have Javascript running. The data in The `<noscript>` tag will only be displayed if javascript is not running.

> Assumption: all browsers work the same. Not true: In order to be
>   unobtrusive to browsers, your script should steer clear of plain
>   errors and compatibility problems, and take special devices such as
>   speech browsers or mobile phones into account.

All browsers do not work the same. You need to be careful with Javascript and CSS (style) to support all the major browsers. Certain functions may be depreciated or unsupported in some browsers.

> Assumption: everybody else will understand my code. Not true: In order
>   to be unobtrusive to fellow programmers, your script should consist of
>   clear, clean code and feature a lot of comments to say what your code
>   is (supposed to be) doing.

You should always try to make your code affective and clear.

Comment: right i understand the noscript part, but what are typical scenarios, work environments, devices that block/disable javascript while viewing webpage. I am wondering whether it is too old to follow.